# Java - Performance difference between long-lived and short-lived objects

Tags: java

In Java, does using short-lived objects instead of long-lived objects when you can causes a difference in performance? (memory usage, speed or both)

Is there really a difference in performance between doing this:

```
MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.my_method();
```

or this:

```
new MyClass().my_method();
```

Thank you!

Comment: This may depend on the JVM, which JVM are you targeting your question to? OpenJDK, Sun JDK, IBM JDK?

Comment: Short vs. long-lived depends on the context around the code.  The way you have written so far yields the same lifetime of the object.  The only difference is that the first example retains a reference to the object on the stack.  But the very next line could clear it.  I suspect that the difference of nanoseconds is insignificant to memory management.  Garbage collection uses generations and I doubt that the extra nanoseconds would move it to a different generation.  But the only way to know for sure is to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you gave does not have any difference in the life of the object.  The real difference is that you have named the variable that holds the object reference.  For the second case, the code will have an anonymous variable that will hold that pointer.  (That is, there will be a space on the stack where the pointer is stored, but you can't access it because it does not have a name.)

At some theoretical level, it is possible that garbage collection might kick while the named variable is in scope, and that might make a microscopic difference, but that is highly unlikely.

In my experience, you should not worry about the performance difference between these, and should base such a decision purely on readability.  The declaration of that variable will be an insignificantly small difference in code execution.  If you need a named variable, use it as if there was no overhead, even if you use the variable only once.  If the code is cleaner from a readability perspective without the variable, then leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some performance with short-living objects, you should use the final declaration. In your example:

```
final MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.my_method();
```

This is a hint to the JVM that it can optimize this away if it feels like, your second example is about the same from the view of the JVM. There is however no guarantee that it happens, as it depends on too many factors to enforce it.

The truly long-living objects are those, that are created once and then reused for a very long time (the entire live-time of the program if possible). There is no immediate gain in performance in the code where they are actually used (beside the usual JVM optimizations), but the GC doesn't have to collect them, and a GC run that doesn't have to happen is execution time saved for more important code. But since the GC is very fast, it is only required to do this in inner loops and other very frequently executed code.